# WSL Alpine: Can't run docker/change datetime

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, alpine-linux

So, i'm starting with WSL. My goal here is run my docker containers in this server.

I installed docker and docker-compose and tried to run a specific container.
The docker response is:

[image]

Then, i checked the date:

[image]

2055 looks strange,
so, i tried to set it manually, but it never changes (tried ntpd, date -s, etc, tzdata).

Below, is ntpd output

[image]

If more data is need, just ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use wsl 1 or wsl 2? Can you run `wsl --list -v` to verify it?

Comment: The above command says 'Invalid Command Line Option: --list", maybe i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you have an oder windows version than 1903? If so, you have to use `/list` instead of `--list`

Comment: If you want to run docker you might need to use WSL 2 which is not available on Windows versions less than 1903 (I think)